# NSURLErrorCancelled when initializing AVPlayerItem in Array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avplayeritem

I'm trying to initialize an AVPlayerItem in an Array like this:

```
func parsePlaylist(json: JSON) {
    var i : Int = 0
    while i < json.count {
        let itemId = json[i]["itemid"].intValue
        let position = json[i]["position"].intValue
        let author = json[i]["author"].stringValue
        let title = json[i]["title"].stringValue
        let url = json[i]["url"].stringValue

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url : json[i]["url"].url!)
        //ERROR - Task <89776295-F9F3-4BBC-8908-5F0201A4CDBB>.<2> finished with error - code: -999

        playlistItem.append(PlaylistItem(myItemId: itemId, myPosition: position, myAuthor: author, myTitle: title, myUrl: url, myPlayerItem: playerItem))
        i += 1
    }
}
```

When doing so, the console is showing json.count-times the Error mentioned above.

Later when trying to init my Player like:

```
var player : AVPlayer?
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playlistItem[itemCounter].playerItem)
```

everything is working fine.

How can I get rid of the Error?
Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using SwiftyJSON to get the Values from the JSON-Object.

Comment: Make sure you are not calling this function from background.

Comment: When testing on real Device Error is different:

`CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sync = syna;
}`

Comment: getting the same error. Did you find a way out??